# Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string

Tags: solidity, testing, hardhat

I am trying to write test for erc20 token and when I try to revert the transaction if the sender has insufficient balance, it is throwing an error.

[image]

Solidity code for transfer function

```
  function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint256 _amount) internal {
    require(balanceOf[_from] >= _amount);
    require(balanceOf[_to] + _amount >= balanceOf[_to]);
    balanceOf[_to] += _amount;
    balanceOf[_from] -= _amount;
    emit Transfer(_from, _to, _amount);
  }
  
  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _amount) public returns(bool) {
    require(msg.sender != address(0) && _to != address(0), "Address cannot be zero");
    _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _amount);
    return true;
  }
```

And the code for test:

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("Blue20", () => {
  let Token, token, owner, addr1, addr2;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("blue20");
    token = await Token.deploy();
    [owner, addr1, addr2, _] = await ethers.getSigners();
  });

  describe("Deployment", () => {
    it("Checking the deployment processs", async () => {
      expect(await token.owner()).to.equal(owner.address);
    });

    it("Should assign the total tokens to the owner", async () => {
      const ownerBalance = await token.balance(owner.address);
      expect(await token.totalSupply()).to.equal(ownerBalance);
    });
  });

  describe("Transactions", () => {
    it("Succesfully transfer the tokens and verify", async () => {
      await token.transfer(addr1.address, 100);
      let addr1Balance = await token.balance(addr1.address);
      expect(await addr1Balance).to.equal(100);

      await token.connect(addr1).transfer(addr2.address, 100);
      let addr2Balance = await token.balance(addr2.address);
      expect(addr2Balance).to.equal(100);
    });

    it("Should fail if sender doesn't have enough tokens", async () => {
      expect(
        await token.connect(addr1).transfer(owner.address, 1)
      ).to.be.revertedWith("Not enough Tokens");
    });
  });
});
```

I use hardhat as development environment.

Comment: Just adding for reffernce but you can also get this error from provider/hardhat if the gas price you set is too high or too low. at the time of writing 5 gwei seems about right

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things you should change in your test. First the **await** keyword should be outside the **expect**. Secondly, for getting the address from signers, you should use **getAddress()**. Try changing your test to:

```
it("Should fail if sender doesn't have enough tokens", async () => {
  await expect(token.connect(addr1).transfer(owner.getAddress(), 1) ).to.be.revertedWith("Not enough Tokens");
});
```

Comment: why should the await keyword be outside? See the response below your response to understand more.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

See on line 23 the await keyword is inside, I try to bring it outside it gives me an error even, the vs code says placing the await keyword there won't affect anything.

But again in line 32 if I place the await keyword inside instead of outside it gives an error, why??